# Looping inside Google's CTemplate

Tags: c++, google-ctemplate

how can I loop in [google-ctemplate](http://code.google.com/p/google-ctemplate/) lib inside a template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections are google-ctemplate answer for loops and conditions.

Syntax:

```
{{#SECTION_NAME}}
Section contents. Can have nested sections.
{{/SECTION_NAME}}
```

Iterate over sections 0 or 1 times - and you'll get if statement. Iterate n times - and you'll get loop.

Comment: but that will be iterating inside c++ code only right ? then why I really need section . I can use any place holder.

Comment: google-ctemplate is a passive template engine. You need to provide all data and to iterate over data in the client application. If you use a simple variable placeholder {{VAR}}, then you'll need to concatenate iterations content on client side. google-ctemplate library have even more functionality as section separators or nested sections.